# Showing the most recent UIAlertView of a particular kind

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview, uilocalnotification

Given :

In my app there are "n"(let suppose A,B,C....) number of different events(scheduled  UILocalNotification). Each event will be fired repeatedly and for each fired event , I want to show one UIAlertView.

Goal :

For each event there should be only one "The most recent" UIAlertView should be showed to user, if he misses the previous alert message.

Example:

I want to schedule the following  medicines

A at time 8:00 AM , 2:00 PM and 6:00 PM

B at time 9:00 AM , 2:00 PM and 7:00 PM

and

C , D .....and so on ...

So, If I do not see the alert message for all the day ....and in evening at 8:00 PM , there should be

only "n" alert message, where "n = number of medicine".

Showing For

A-> "Take medicine A at 6:00PM"

B-> "Take medicine B at 7:00PM"

Thanks in Advance

--

Anupam

Comment: do u want to show only one alertview at a time?

Comment: @Saad : Yes , I want to show one alert view for A ,one for B and so one ...at a time.

Comment: @NikhilBansal : Good option. Thanks a lot. I wish that will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly without seeing how you are launching your alerts, but in the method where you show an alert, check to see if an alert for that event is on screen, and if it is, dismiss it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a quick reply. Hopefully that should work :)